# Building workbox into angular using custom esbuilder

Tags: angular, workbox, esbuild-plugin

I'm using Angular 17 and NX. I want to build my workbox service worker in the same build process as angular and not in a separate build step, because that would mean that I could not test my service worker using `nx serve myApp`. I would have to `nx build myApp`, then build my service-worker and then run the thing using another http-server alltogether.

## What I got so far:

1. Replaced all occurrences of `@angular-devkit/build-angular` with `@nx/angular` in my `project.json`
2. Added the following under `targets.build.options`: `"plugins": ["apps/myApp/wbInject.plugin.ts"]`
3. Created `apps/myApp/wbInject.plugin.ts`:

```
import * as esbuild from 'esbuild';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

const MATCH_FILES = /^.+\.(js|css|svg|img|html|txt|webmanifest)$/i;
const manifest: { url: string; revision: string }[] = [];
const projectRoot = 'apps/myApp/src';

const wbInject: esbuild.Plugin = {
  name: 'wbInject',
  setup(build: esbuild.PluginBuild) {
    // Append ngsw-worker to entry points
    // This is done so that it is discoverable in the onEnd hook
    const options = build.initialOptions;
    Object.assign(options.entryPoints || {}, {
      'ngsw-worker': path.resolve(projectRoot, 'ngsw-worker.ts'),
    });
    let workerCode = '';

    // Pre-build the worker, so that we get a single module for this
    // as angular would chunk it otherwise
    build.onStart(async () => {
      console.log('Building service-worker');
      const result = await esbuild.build({
        entryPoints: [projectRoot + '/ngsw-worker.ts'],
        bundle: true,
        write: false,
        platform: 'browser',
        target: 'es2017',
      });
      workerCode = result.outputFiles[0].text;
    });

    // Inject manifest into worker
    build.onEnd(async result => {
      if (result.errors.length !== 0) return;

      // Add build output to manifest
      const files = result.outputFiles?.filter(f => f.path.match(MATCH_FILES) && !f.path.match(/ngsw-worker/)) || [];
      for (const file of files) await addToManifest(file.path, file.contents);

      const workerFile = result.outputFiles?.find(file => file.path.match(/ngsw-worker.*\.js$/));
      const workerSourceMap = result.outputFiles?.find(file => file.path.match(/ngsw-worker.*\.js.map$/));
      if (!workerFile) return;

      // Remove cache busting from worker file
      [workerFile, ...(workerSourceMap != null ? [workerSourceMap] : [])].forEach(
        file => (file.path = file.path.replace(/\-[A-Z0-9]{8}\./, '.')),
      );

      // Inject manifest into worker
      const updatedWorkerCode = workerCode.replace('self.__WB_MANIFEST', JSON.stringify(manifest));

      // Update the worker file in the output
      workerFile.contents = new TextEncoder().encode(updatedWorkerCode);
    });
  },
};

async function addToManifest(filePath: string, contents?: Uint8Array) {
  const relPath = path.relative(process.cwd(), filePath);
  if (manifest.findIndex(i => i.url === relPath) !== -1) return;

  const content = contents || (await readFileSync(path.resolve(projectRoot, relPath)));
  const hash = await createHash(content);
  manifest.push({ url: relPath, revision: hash });
}

async function createHash(content: BufferSource) {
  const hash: ArrayBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', content);
  return Array.from(new Uint8Array(hash))
    .map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
    .join('');
}

export default wbInject;
```

So this does two things:

1. hook into the build process, add a new entrypoint for my serviceworker file `ngsw-worker.ts`*, build the file separately and inject the result into the final build output.
2. Analyze the build output and create a manifest of entries (*minus the service-worker itself*) and inject that into my service-worker.

*: (*the name is because we replaced angular service-worker with workbox and did not want to confuse browsers where this app is already installed*)

Now you are asking; can't you just use workbox own injectManifest function for this? Well, first off it relies on disk content. And when building using `nx serve myApp`, esbuild does not write to disk. Secondly InjectManifest is based on webpack which fits poorly into an esbuild context.

## The problem

The esbuild `result.outputFiles` only seem to contain the built javascript chunks, and not css, assets and html files. These files should also be a part of the workbox pre-cache. How can I retreive these files from the build process?